# Charge cards infrequently with PayPal possible?

Tags: paypal, payment, credit-card

I'm selling a print magazine (physical object) that comes out every 3-4 months, so the period is not always 100% frequent. I know that PayPal can process reoccurring payments such as monthly online subscriptions. However, in my case, I'd like to be able to store people's credit card (or have them stored by PP) and manually initiate a charge whenever a new issue is out.

Is this possible with PayPal? Maybe with its new RestAPI? Or an external tool? Thanks!

Kai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with PayPal.  You have quite a few options.

You could use Reference Transactions.  This involves the DoReferenceTransaction API, which accepts the transaction ID of a previous authorization or sale transaction as well as the amount you'd like to charge for the new transaction.  The system will use the billing info PayPal has saved to charge the new amount without any further approval.

If you're doing this with Payments Pro there's not much special to it.  You just process an initial transaction and then use that transaction ID in future calls to DoReferenceTransaction to process variable amounts at variable times.

If you're doing this with Express Checkout you need to make sure and include billing agreement info in your SetExpressCheckout request. DoReferenceTransaction won't work for you on Express Checkout transactions without a billing agreement setup.

Another option would be to use the Adaptive Payments platform, specifically Preapproval and Pay.  You can use the Preapproval API to have users create the profile with your application.  From that point on your application can use the Pay API and include the preapproval key for the payer on any particular transaction to submit payments accordingly.

The new REST API does have the ability to "store a credit card" and use it for future payments, but I don't think it has a way to do the same with Express Checkout yet.  I could be wrong about that, though.

I personally still prefer Express Checkout with billing agreements and Payments Pro (for direct credit cards.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm based in Australia and there seems to be a few different PayPal versions (different to US): https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products

I'm currently using Express Checkout, but I'd like to change this so I can have a simple credit card form on my own site. All of what you said above is new to me and I'm just trying to dig through the API info on their site. 

Any idea on how I can actually get access to this? Would I have to call them and explain what I'd like to do?

Comment: If you want to process cards directly you can either use the new REST API or signup for Payments Pro.

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my comment above, we don't have Payments Pro in Australia. It seems to be a more complicated process which involves getting a 3rd party merchant account... :( Thanks though!

Comment: Andrew, if you could clarify one more question: it seems like reoccurring billing as described above based on a reference transaction only works with people checking out through Checkout Express (and logging into their PayPal account to approve). Am I correct that this does *not* work for people that want to avoid using PP and pay with their cc directly?

Comment: That is true with Express Checkout, but you could use Payments Pro or the REST API to give users the option of direct credit cards as well.